# Oracle Apex parameter in URL

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to pass a parameter in this page:

http://serviciosweb.ccss.sa.cr/pls/APEXPRD/APEX/f?p=162:1:7334566735152::::P1_CEDULA:123456789

the item P1_CEDULA is on that page and works if I use it in the same web browser where I generated it from the Apex console, but, doesn't work if I use it in a different web browser or if I try to use it in a different computer.

The situation that happens is that the session numer changes and the parameter name and its value is erased.

Someone can help me ? Thanks.

Comment: I imagine that's because your new session/browser/machines doesn't have an appropriate cookie. If you look at your browser's developer tools you'll probably see a request with no cookie getting a 302 redirect and the response then getting a session cookie back?

Comment: Well, in any of the test that I've made, I didn't see a request for cookies or any other detail related with cokkies.

Comment: [This is what dev tools shows me for that URL](https://ibb.co/QrNRq48). I have no idea how to change the behaviour, or even if you can, but that seems to be what's happening.

Comment: What is your goal when you use that URL on a different computer?  That you'd be logged in automatically to your old session without going through the login screen again?  That a new session would be created for you without going through the login screen?  That you'd be sent to the login screen and once you logged in that you'd be sent to this page/ have the parameter populated?  That you can get to this page with no authentication in a different session?

Comment: The whole idea for the page that I posted, it's to use it in call from a page made in PHP, this other page should open the link and place the value of the parameter. This apex page must be used from many people with any web browser in different devices, like PCs, tablets or cell phones. The login procedure will be in the PHP page.

Comment: You can't shared URLs with the session ID, expecting the other browser/computer to blindly accept it. This is a security feature of APEX. You may be interested in a related feature called "Rejoin session", introduced from 5.0 http://deneskubicek.blogspot.com/2014/06/apex-50-rejoin-session.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand you should not use session in the link. Just pass the item and value.
Some what like this

http://serviciosweb.ccss.sa.cr/pls/APEXPRD/APEX/f?p=162:1:::::P1_CEDULA:123456789

Hope this would work.